# Spring Elastic Search java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException using mongo @DBRef

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch, spring-data-mongodb, spring-data-elasticsearch

I have a spring boot application where i want to use my documents in MongoRepositories and ElasticsearchRepositories at the same time.

As soon as i use in the @Document the @DBRef annotation from mongoDb, the ElasticSearch repositories cannot be created anymore during the application startup and i get the error:

**java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException**

My Entities:

```
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.TypeAlias;
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.annotations.Document;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.DBRef;

import java.util.List;



@Document(indexName = "ps")
@TypeAlias("person")
@Getter
@Setter
public class Person {

    @Id
    private String id;

    @DBRef
    private List<Address> addresses;
}
```

```
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document;

@org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.annotations.Document(indexName = "address")
@Document(collection = "address")
@Getter
@Setter
public class Address {
    @Id
    private String id;

    private String streetname;

}
```

The Configuration

```
package backend.configuration;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.config.EnableElasticsearchRepositories;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.config.EnableMongoRepositories;

@EnableMongoRepositories(basePackages = "backend.repositories.mongo")
@EnableElasticsearchRepositories(basePackages = "backend.repositories.elastic")
@Configuration
public class BackendConfiguration {
}
```

The ElasticSearch Repository

```
package backend.repositories.elastic;


import backend.models.Person;
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.ElasticsearchRepository;


public interface ElasticPersonRepository extends ElasticsearchRepository<Person,String> {
}
```

The Errormessage

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'elasticPersonRepository' defined in me.rip.backend.repositories.elastic.ElasticPersonRepository defined in @EnableElasticsearchRepositories declared on BackendConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1786) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:602) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:925) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918) ~[spring-context-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145) ~[spring-boot-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754) ~[spring-boot-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:434) ~[spring-boot-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:338) ~[spring-boot-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1343) ~[spring-boot-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1332) ~[spring-boot-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at me.rip.backend.BackendApplication.main(BackendApplication.java:17) ~[main/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: null
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.mapping.SimpleElasticsearchPersistentProperty.createAssociation(SimpleElasticsearchPersistentProperty.java:278) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-4.2.2.jar:4.2.2]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.AbstractPersistentProperty.lambda$new$0(AbstractPersistentProperty.java:84) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.getNullable(Lazy.java:230) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.orElse(Lazy.java:169) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.AbstractPersistentProperty.getAssociation(AbstractPersistentProperty.java:271) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PersistentProperty.getRequiredAssociation(PersistentProperty.java:188) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext$PersistentPropertyCreator.createAndRegisterProperty(AbstractMappingContext.java:556) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext$PersistentPropertyCreator.doWith(AbstractMappingContext.java:521) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithFields(ReflectionUtils.java:710) ~[spring-core-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.addPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:384) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.getPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:258) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.getPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:201) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.getPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:87) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$6(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:326) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.ifPresent(Optional.java:176) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:326) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.ElasticsearchRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(ElasticsearchRepositoryFactoryBean.java:69) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-4.2.2.jar:4.2.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1845) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1782) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    ... 16 common frames omitted
```

Is there a way to continue using @DBReg annotations i.e. by ignoring them for the elasticsearch mapping?

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question: No.

The code that is used in Spring Data Elasticsearch to set up the property mapping (using `PersistentEntities` and `PersistentProperties` is common to all Spring Data modules.

This code checks if a property is annotated with `@Reference`; this is an annotation from the Spring data base module marking a property that marks an association to a different entity. Not all Spring Data datastores support associations, Spring Data Elasticsearch does not.

The problem now is that Spring Data Elasticsearch does not care about `@DBRef`, but `@DBRef` itself is annotated with `@Reference` and so any property annotated with `@DBRef` is a `@Reference`as well. And then the code from Spring Data commons tries to create the association which is not supported by Spring Data Elasticsearch.

What can you do? Use different entities for the different datastores and map your original entity to these store specific entities.

Comment: Thank you for that information. Using different entities requires me to use different repositories and service classes and needs additional code to keep the both stores in sync.

i will now go for the integrated search in mongo cloud atlas (based on lucene).